# How do i get manifest.json file in C#.net?

Tags: c#, azure, bots, microsoft-teams, manifest.json

i have referred following link to create bot and deploy it into microsoft teams
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams
But when it need add manifest.json file in Microsoft teams,i did not get manifest.json in c#.net
How do i get manifest.json file in c#.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manifest file is the zip file that will contain a json file which lists out all the capabilities your app offers and the two icons of the app. You could use [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/app-studio-overview) to create your app manifest. Or you can [sideload the app manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-upload) if you have the manifest file ready. Here is a [sample manifest](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-csharp/tree/master/Microsoft.Teams.Samples.HelloWorld.Web/Manifest) file. Please let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

i have used core bot framework template from Visual studio and created bot, then i did app registration on below url
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade
Then  Used Microsoft app Id and Microsoft password  on  "https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new"  link  to create  bot and added endpoint as https://113526c2.ngrok.io/api/messages 
Then used Microsoft App id and App password in c#.net code ,  configured  Microsoft App id and App password which get from app registartion  and  endpoint url as https://113526c2.ngrok.io/api/messages on bot framework emulator
But bot is not working on bot framework, why?, Post 400 error display on bot emulator 
How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to get a manifest is to use the "App Studio" app in Teams. [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/app-studio-overview) is an actual app, in the store, from Microsoft, that you can use for a bunch of things. One of those is to create a new app *for* Teams, inside of Teams. It has a proper GUI so you can create your app definition, modify and update it, etc., and then export the manifest when you're done. It will generate a zip file, which contains the manifest itself, as well as your app's icons.

However, while you're still building the app, App Studio helps you to deploy (and redeploy over time) the app manually into your own context (e.g. a 1-1 bot, or into a group chat or a Teams channel). It's also got some validation in as you're going to check that you've entered things correctly.

So, in short, very highly recommended for building apps for Teams, and comes directly from Microsoft. As an extra bit of info, you need the ability to side-load custom apps to be able to deploy your apps into Teams using App Studio.